# difference in physical path, root path, virtual path, relative virtual path, application path and absolute path?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-3.5

I have some confusion in understanding what is different in various paths available in .Net for a resource.

I only guess Physical path is OS directory path for a resource. I am confuse and event can't tell about what path basically I need to use.

Answer (score 14):

In regards to an ASP.NET application I think of it like this:

**Physical Path:** OS path using drive/directory/file in which the actual app doesnt really use this path but if it did it would be mapped using a virtual path. A physical path is how the OS locates the resource/s 
ie: `c:\\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnetapp` The actual app only cares about paths relative to its root directory.

**Root Path:** This would be the URI or URL at the root of your aspnetapp or `~/Home/Index` with proper route config (Not to be confused with Unix Root Directory naming convention). `http://www.yardpenalty.com` could actually be the location of this example's physical path in terms of an OS/NOS.

**Virtual Path or Relative Virtual Path:** The path that the application identifies or is identified by from its Web server.

For instance, in IIS (or OWIN) you may have a resource directory for your images in folder `c:\\inetpub\ftp\images` but the developer maps this folder to the app like so... `~\Images`. So think of this as the ability to create a relative path to resources identifiable by your app and its users while physically located elsewhere.

I would imagine that using a virtual path under a root application would be helpful in development when there are one or more projects that the developer wishes to give the appearance of a single application under a single domain.

**Absolute Path:** The entire path to a resource. 
Let's say you have a link that takes you to a specific route like this:
`<a href="http://www.yardpenalty.com/home/about"> About</a>`. If this link was in the layout or master page a relative path `<a href="~/home/about">About</a>` would be cleaner. There are instances when you need to hard code an absolute path but it is typically wiser to use relative paths especially when development involves migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Relative path to the current working directory - Sometimes you can find a path description in a format like this `./Directory/Filename.Ext` and it means that the path is specified relatively to the current application working directory.